# const url = {process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE} SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a file in `mongo.js` where I have set an ENV variable like so:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const express = require('express');
const url = {process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE}
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
```

When I try to run `node mongo.js` I receive this error:

```
/Users/drubio/Desktop/react_personal_website/src/modules/mongo.js:5
const url = {process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE}
                    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

According to create-react-app, I should be able to set environment variables this way. I have even created a `.env` file and the contents of the file has the url that I want to connect to:

```
REACT_APP_DATABASE = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/danielrubio'
```

Why am I getting this syntax error. I've restarted both servers so it should work.

Comment: remove the brackets?

Comment: Not an expert in React, but try `const url = process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE;`?

Comment: Yeah that worked sure enough although Create-React-App says to do otherwise https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables. Thanks.

Comment: Well, JSX code is not JavaScript code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not valid JavaScript syntax:

```
const url = { process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE }
```

If you are creating an object literal, it needs to be in **[key]:[value]** format:

```
const url = { url: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE}
```

However, if you are trying to just get the variable:

```
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE;
```