# Why is this if/else statement for setting a NODE_ENV returning undefined as opposed to the correct string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a `mongo.js` file in my react application that I want to set an environment variable to the correct database. I do this dynamically with the following code at the top of my file:

```
let url = '';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
  url = process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE;
else
  url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
```

Wen I try to start the node server I get this error `TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined` Why is it evaluating to undefined as opposed to the correct string?

Comment: Seems like either `process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE` or `process.env.MONGODB_URI` doesn't exist.

Comment: I have `REACT_APP_DATABASE` defined in my .env file so according to create-react-app's documentation it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Either  `process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE`  or `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is being assigned and is undefined.  Have you examined the values in a debugger?

Comment: According to the documentation on https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables I have set my .env file to have the env variable `REACT_APP_DATABASE`. Also I asked a previous question here that told me to set the variable as so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898469/const-url-process-env-react-app-database-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/40898696#40898696 It doesn't seem to be working now for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an oversight in my `package.json` file. It looks like I had not installed `dotenv`. Oops.